# Solve a second order ode using numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numerical-methods, ode

Consider this second order ODE ($D=A \frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+B \frac{dx}{dt}$):

[image: LinearODE]

with A, B and D being constants

How can I solve for x(t) using numpy? I have no idea how to even begin the problem

Comment: I remember that you can transfer every N-order ODE into N ODEs of order one. This is always the first step to so...ve it numerically. But you could probably also solve it analytically looks not so hard.

Comment: You can do it with numpy if you program your own solver, the existing solvers of the python project can be found in `scipy.integrate`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55989100/runge-kutta-4th-order-to-solve-2nd-order-ode-system, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52985027/runge-kutta-4-and-pendulum-simulation, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52334558/runge-kutta-4th-order-method-to-solve-second-order-odes